# MySQLi Prepared Statements - Displaying a table

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am making a webpage which will list all user accounts in a table. When trying the method from w3schools, it did not work. How would I be able to do this with PHP prepared statements? I have this code so far but it will only display the first MySQLi result as many times as the amount of users in the database.

```
<?php
while($totalusers > 0) {
    if($stmt = $con -> prepare("SELECT id, username, confirmed FROM users")) {
        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmt -> bind_result($id, $username, $confirmed);
        $stmt -> fetch();
        $stmt -> close();
    }
    $totalusers = $totalusers-1;
    echo "<tr><td>" . $id . "</td><td>" . $username . "</td><td>" . $confirmed . "</td></tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: *"How would I be able to do this with PHP prepared statements?"* --- Here is a pretty good tutorial on [**prepared statements**](http://www.phpmysqlitutorials.com/2011/04/16/mysqli-whats-the-difference-between-standard-queries-and-prepared-statements/) <=

Answer (score 0):

You prepared the statement and execute it $totaluser times.
You only need to prepare and execute it once.
Try this:

```
if($stmt = $con -> prepare("SELECT id, username, confirmed FROM users")) {
        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmt -> bind_result($id, $username, $confirmed);
        while($stmt->fetch()) {
            echo "<tr><td>" . $id . "</td><td>" . $username . "</td><td>" . $confirmed . "</td></tr>";
        }
        $stmt -> close();
}
```

i don't test the code, so it might need some tweaking.
If this is the first time you use PHP, [php.net](http://www.php.net/) is a great place for learning PHP.

Comment: Most of it seems nice. The bind_result needs to go after execute() though. If I am already using bind_result, would while($result->fetch_assoc()) {} work? If I didn't bind_result, than could I potentially use $myrow['username'] to replace $username?

Comment: You could. I prefer to just use fetch_assoc and then use $myrow['id'], $myrow['username'] and $myrow['confirmed'] in while loop than bind_result.